# HTML Audio embed not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, audio

On my website I have put in audio. It works fine in Chrome, with autoplay and loop, but with IE it says "An unknown error occurred". The audio file is "ComicSans.mp3", and here is the coding:

```
<body bgcolor="#5e54e8">    
<a class="GeneratedLink" href="http://georgeocodes.github.io/" target="_blank"">George O Codes</a>
<audio controls>
<audio src="ComicSans.mp3" controls autoplay loop> 
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<marquee direction="right" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; font-family: Comic Sans MS; background-color: #5e54e8;">Lock your doors and hide your children. This is the invasion of Comic Sans.</marquee>
<marquee direction="right" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; font-family: Comic Sans MS; background-color: #5e54e8;">Lock your doors and hide your children. This is the invasion of Comic Sans.</marquee>
<marquee direction="right" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; font-family: Comic Sans MS; background-color: #5e54e8;">Lock your doors and hide your children. This is the invasion of Comic Sans.</marquee>
<marquee direction="right" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; font-family: Comic Sans MS; background-color: #5e54e8;">Lock your doors and hide your children. This is the invasion of Comic Sans.</marquee>
</body>
```

There were a LOT more marquee tags, but I cut most of them.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? `audio` tag is only supported form IE9 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have for the audio is invalid. If you check the [HTML5 definition for the `audio` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-audio-element), the closing tag is mandatory. It works on Chrome and Firefox, but not on IE because of the way in which each browser interprets the invalid code:

```
<audio controls>
    <audio src="ComicSans.mp3" controls autoplay loop> 
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

---

To fix the issue, just remove the first `<audio controls>` and the sound will work in all the browsers:

```html
<audio src="http://comicsanswillrule.github.io/ComicSans.mp3" controls autoplay loop> 
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```